# When to appreciate the miracle of the body

Tags: blessing, medicine, asher-yatzar

Why doesn't one recite asher yatzar after coming back from a dangerous operation?

Surely this is also an apt time for giving thanks for the miracle of the body!

Comment: going to the bathroom is also a dangerous operation. so many things need to work smoothly to prepare the waste material and expel it. we are just used to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is another blessing prescribed by our Sages for when coming back from a dangerous operation. *Birkat Hagomel* is said after being healed from sickness

> according to Ashkenazim, for sickness that’s non-mortal but confines a
>   person to bed for 3 days or more [...], according to Sephardim, for
>   any sickness which confines a person to bed for any amount of time. ([Halachipedia](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Birkat_HaGomel))

That blessing is more ceremonial than *asher yatzar* in that it is said in front of 10 men and preferably in the presence of a Torah scroll. For details see [Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 61:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Kitzur_Shulchan_Aruch.61.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) and [SA OC 219:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.219.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) and ff or here on [chabad.org](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/115308/jewish/The-Laws-of-the-Blessing-of-Thanksgiving.htm).

In any case I am not convinced *asher yatzar* would be appropriate after a dangerous operation. It is a blessing which celebrates the wonders of the human body which performs well ("[to give praise to Hashem for creating man with great wisdom](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Birchat_Asher_Yatzar)"), while by definition an operation was required to correct something that didn't work so well anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Besides mbloch's good answer,

As soon as the operation is over, there is a recovery period and a time to see for sure if it was a success, or another operation is needed.

Therefore, you will spend a significant amount of time, before knowing if it is the correct moment to say a potential asher yatzar. In that time, you will have most likely gone to the bathroom once (or more times). So, you can easily have the operation in mind when you say asher yatzar the very next time.